# How do I implement autocomplete with cursoradapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, autocomplete, android-cursoradapter

I have an SQLite database containing 2 tables 4000+ rows each used for autocomplete. I saw very simple examples that use an array of strings to provide autocomplete or they use the list of contacts to do the same. Obviously none of these work in my case. How do I use my own SQLite database with my own autocomplete data, for the autocomplete. Do I have to create content providers? How? Please give me some examples because I couldn't find any. I have managed to override `SQLiteOpenHelper` to copy the database from the assets folder to the /data/data/MY_PACKAGE/databases/ folder on the android. I have created a custom `CursorAdapter` that uses my custom `SQLiteOpenHelper` and returns a cursor from `runQueryOnBackgroundThread`. I get strange errors about some _id column missing. I have added the _id column to my tables. I also don't understand what is the Filterable interface doing and when does my data get filtered. What methods/classes do I need to override? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works.

You need the SQLiteOpenHelper from [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). You basically have to copy your database into a specific folder from your assets folder.  Then you need a custom CursorAdapter that uses your custom SQLiteOpenHelper.

Here is the onCreate method for my activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        KeywordsCursorAdapter kwadapter = new KeywordsCursorAdapter(this, null);

        txtKeyword = (AutoCompleteTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtKeyword);
        txtKeyword.setAdapter(kwadapter);
        txtCity = (AutoCompleteTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtCity);
        btnSearch = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Here is the cursoradapter. You can pass null for cursor when constructing.

```
public class KeywordsCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public KeywordsCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        this.context = context;
    }

    //I store the autocomplete text view in a layout xml.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.keyword_autocomplete, null);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String keyword = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("keyword"));
        TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtAutocomplete);
        tv.setText(keyword);
    }

    //you need to override this to return the string value when
    //selecting an item from the autocomplete suggestions
    //just do cursor.getstring(whatevercolumn);
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        //return super.convertToString(cursor);
        String value = "";
        switch (type) {
        case Keywords:
            value = cursor.getString(DatabaseHelper.KEYWORD_COLUMN);
            break;
        case Cities:
            value = cursor.getString(DatabaseHelper.CITY_COLUMN);
            break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        //return super.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(constraint);
        String filter = "";
        if (constraint == null) filter = "";
        else
            filter = constraint.toString();
                //I have 2 DB-s and the one I use depends on user preference
        SharedPreferences prefs  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        //String selectedCountryCode = prefs.getString("selectedCountry", "GB");
        String selectedCountryCode = prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.settings_selected_country), "GB");
        selectedCountryCode += "";

                //Here i have a static SQLiteOpenHelper instance that returns a cursor.
        Cursor cursor = MyApplication.getDbHelpers().get(selectedCountryCode.toLowerCase()).getKeywordsCursor(filter);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Here is the part that returns the cursor: it's just a select with a like condition.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

...

    public synchronized Cursor getKeywordsCursor (String prefix) {
        if (database == null) database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {"_id", "keyword"};
        String[] args = {prefix};

        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = database.query("keywords", columns, "keyword like '' || ? || '%'", args, null, null, "keyword", "40");

        int idcol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
        int kwcol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("keyword");

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(idcol);
            String kw = cursor.getString(kwcol);
            Log.i("keyword", kw);
        }

        cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
        return cursor;
    }

...

}
```

You can also create a custom content provider but in this case it would be just another useless class you need to override.

Comment: What does that select condition means?

Comment: `select _id,keyword from keywords where keyword like '' || ? || '%'`. `?` is the parameter. `||` is concatenation. I wasn't sure how to convert the parameter to a string that is why I concatenated with an empty string. It should probably be  `? || '%'`

Comment: I have a similar problem but I just can't get it fixed:|...               cursor = database.query("keywords", columns, "keyword like '' || ? || '%'", args, null, null, "keyword", "40");.....Now,the first "keywords" is the name of the table?    And still don't  get it what u mean by "keyword like '' || ? || '%'"....                                          IS "keyword like" a message that can't be replaced????   "?" is the parameter....still don't get it.If u could explain me a little bit more further I would appreciate it

Comment: and another thing..... public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint)  returns a new cursor but it doesn't filter the entries of the autocomplete...u have to setup a filter and u didn't do nothing like in u code:)

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea how the data is filtered.

Comment: Here an example for sql like syntax: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqllike.html. `?` is just a parameter, it will be replaced with a valid string at runtime by sqlite. I think for every character pressed `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` is executed and a new cursor is returned. Yes I probably SHOULD reuse the cursor, but I was glad that I finally got it working, I didn't optimize it.